# Azure: Build templates: how to extract defaultStorageAccount

Tags: powershell, azure, build-templates

I am trying to create a custom image in my Azure DevTestLab, from a vhd image stored in the default storage account.

I started modifying the file at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/blob/master/ARMTemplates/201-dtl-create-customimage-from-vhd/azuredeploy.json) for ARM templates for creating a custom image from a vhd.

I have already created the DevTest lab, and I can run the following Powershell command to get its data:

```
PS C:\git> $rid = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName jgTl9-rg -ResourceType Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs -ResourceName jgTl9 -ApiVersion 2016-05-15
```

This yields a bunch of information. If I want to extract the default storage account name, I do the following:

```
PS C:\git> $rid.properties.defaultStorageAccount
```

So I know it's possible to get it.  Now I have modified the variables section of the Azure build template (a JSON file) to look as follows:

```
"variables": {
  "resourceName": "[concat(variables('existingLabName'), '/', variables('imageName'))]",
  "resourceType": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/customimages", 
  "existingLabName": "[replace(resourceGroup().name,'-rg','')]",
  "storageAccountID": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/jgTl9-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/djgtl91795",
  "saidFrags": "[skip(split(variables('storageAccountID'), '/' ), add(length(split(variables('storageAccountID'), '/' )),-1) ) ]",  
  "storageAccountSuffix": "[take(variables('saidFrags'),1)[0]]",
  "existingVhdUri": "[concat('https://',variables('storageAccountSuffix'),'.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/',parameters('imageFileName'))]",
  "imageName": "JaysImage"
```

},

This code actually works when I call the New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment command with the azuredeploy.json and azuredeploy.parameters.json.

However, instead of hardcoding the **storageAccountID** variable, I'd like to extract the defaultStorageAccount from the environment. I tried something like this:

```
   "storageAccountID": "[string( resourceId(resourceGroup().name,'MicrosoftDevTestLab/labs','jgTl9').properties.defaultStorageAccount  ))",
```

I tried a few variations on this but nothing worked. What is the syntax I need to use to extract the same information as I have hardcoded for the storageAccountID?

(I could not find anything in [Microsoft's description of template functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions)).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues with your following expression

```
"storageAccountID": "[string( resourceId(resourceGroup().name,'MicrosoftDevTestLab/labs','jgTl9').properties.defaultStorageAccount  ))",
```

1. There is syntax issue ie. an extra `)` at the end.
2. The resource provider `MicrosoftDevTestlab/labs` should be `Microsoft.DevTestlab/labs`
3. When `resourceId` is used it will not give you the entire object. So when you do `properties.defaultStorageAccount` it will not work. Because it gives you just the string of your dev test lab and nothing else and there is no property on a string of `defaultStorageAccount`.

Now what you need is `reference` function like below

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {    
  },
  "variables": {
    "vDefaultStorageAccount": "[string(resourceId('yourResourceGroupName','Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs','yourTestLabName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {        
    "defaultStorageAccount":{
      "value": "[reference(variables('vDefaultStorageAccount'),'2016-05-15').defaultStorageAccount]",
      "type":"string"
    }        
  }
}
```

In the variable, `vDefaultStorageAccount` we get the ID of the `DevTestLab` and then we use `reference` function to get the object. Then you can do `.` to get properties. You don't need to do properties.defaultStorageAccount for example.